# How can I recover an encrypted home folder on a partition where resizing it made those files disappear?

Tags: partitioning, 15.04, encryption, data-recovery

I had a partition that contained my Ubuntu 15.04 installation. I wanted to shrink the volume with gparted but as soon as I did that my entire encrypted home directory disappeared, so I extended the partition back to its original size, and I never touched the disk again. I have the recovery passphrase. I just don't know how to recover or search for the encrypted home directory file to try the recovery passphrase against.